# load tabBarController programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard

The objective is to load the tabBarController from a function. How do I do this? I found this code from another answer, but it doesn't work as intended; once the function is called, the simulation just closes, no error or SIGABRTs (simulating on a real iPhone 6, not the simulator version)

```
         var tbc = UITabBarController()      

         tbc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("tabBarController") as! UITabBarController            
         tbc.selectedIndex=1;
         self.presentViewController(tbc, animated: true, completion: {() -> Void in })
```

Any idea?

Comment: Where did you call this code? Do you have tab bar controller in your storyboard with identifier "tabBarController"?

Comment: I've tried calling it anywhere, I've got it set up so a button will call the function at the moment (not the end goal). Yes, the tabBarController is the tab bar controller in the storyboard set with that storyboard ID. Is that the correct way?

Comment: Found a different solution, thought I'd post it for anyone watching over. I created a Modal Segue in the storyboard and called it from the function I wanted. Looks like this:

self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goToTBC", sender: nil)

and set "goToTBC" as the Segue Identifier.